# open log file at end of Powershell script

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell script that writes to a log file (log.txt).  What command(s) will work at the end of the script to open this log file automatically on the computer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would work:

```
Invoke-item log.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few options

You can just call the file using relative path

```
.\log.txt
```

using notepad.exe to open the file

```
notepad.exe .\log.txt
```

use Invoke-Item

```
ii .\log.txt
Invoke-Item .\log.txt
```

or if you want the content to write to the host you're running the script in

```
# You may also use 'Clear-Host'
Clear 
Get-Content ".\log.txt"
```

shorthand:

```
cls
gc .\log.txt
```